# Can I run arbitary command on remote server via tcpserver?

Tags: tcp, daemon

I know `tcpserver` can run a specific command for each connection. My question is, can I run arbitary command on remote server via `tcpserver`?

Comment: It's trivial to set it up to run arbitrary commands, but that's basically the biggest security hole you can make on your computer unless you know exactly what you are doing in a perfectly sealed network. Because it has no security (authentication, encryption, etc.) Use SSH :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The job of `tcpserver` is only to dispatch incoming connections to a program, and perform some IP-based access control and a bit of load monitoring. It does not read the content of the TCP stream: that's the job of the program invoked by `tcpserver`.

To run an arbitrary command on a remote server, the server should be running an SSH server. You would of course need an account and a way to authenticate (typically a password or key): as a rule people don't want random people to run arbitrary commands on their computers.